# If 10 needles are dropped on the floor, how many needles are expected to cross a line?

Tags: probability, statistics

If 10 needles are dropped on the floor, how many needles are expected to cross over one of the lines?

This is a variation of the Buffon Needle problem (short needle). I believe that the probability of a singular needle dropping is $\frac{2L}{\pi}$, where L is the length of the needle. Would I simply multiply it together 10 times? I'm not quite sure what to do?

Comment: Have you learned about the expectation of a probability distribution? If so, then that is the answer, due to the linearity of expectation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the probability of one needle crossing a line as $p$ (thus forming an indicator random variable), simply multiply that by $10$ to get your result. This is linearity of expectation and works even if the variables are not independent.

Answer (score 2):

Here you would want to use expected value. So,

$$\sum_{s \in S} X(s) \cdot p(s)$$

$X(s)$ is the "random variable" of the needle, and then $p(s)$ is the probablitiy. $s \in S$ is saying the $s$ is an element of our sample space ($S$).